# Multiple Nunjucks files with different JSON data using gulp

Tags: json, gulp, nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render, gulp-data

I would like to use gulp and Nunjucks to generate multiple template files at once with varying content. These templates will all have the exact same layout, but pass in different variables for text/images.

I am able to successfully generate a single `index.html` file, but am unsure how to set this up for multiple files to be created at once. Here is a simplified version of what I have:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var nunjucks = require('gulp-nunjucks-render');
var data     = require('gulp-data');

gulp.task('nunjucks', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('./src/layouts/**/*.+(html|nunjucks)')
        .pipe(data(function () { return require('./src/data.json'); }))
        .pipe(nunjucks({ path: ['./src/templates'] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

**layout.nunjucks**

```
<head>
    {% block title %} {% endblock %}
</head>
```

**index.nunjucks**

```
{% extends "layout.nunjucks" %}

{% block title %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
{% endblock %}
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "title": "DEFAULT"
}
```

What is the best way to alter this workflow to generate multiple files where each has a different title?

I've found that I can create multiple `index.nunjucks` files, but it looks like they all use the same `data.json` file. I also wouldn't want to make a separate JSON file for each.

Could I add an array to my `data.json` file to have Nunjucks loop through and create a separate file for each object found? Such as the following:

**data.json**

```
{
    "files": [{
        "title": "DEFAULT",
    }, {
        "title": "DEFAULT #2"
    }]
}
```

Or is there a way to set variables within the `index.nunjucks` file without relying on storing them in JSON?

Comment: I've never used gulp-data or nunjucks so ....  But if don't want to create separate files for each as the gulp-data examples do, how about creating a key within your data.json file that ties the file-basename to "title" and then using {title-basename} in your template.  Your data() would examine the current path.basename, add it title+path.basename and return that from data.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way to do this: in each Nunjucks index file, I set a variable named `email` to the filename and updated my `data.json` file with a new object matching the filename with its own content.

**default.nunjucks**

```
{% set email = default %}

{% include "index.nunjucks" %}
```

**test.nunjucks**

```
{% set email = test %}

{% include "index.nunjucks" %}
```

**index.nunjucks**

```
{% extends "layout.nunjucks" %}

{% block title %}
    <title>{{ email.title }}</title>
{% endblock %}
```

**layout.nunjucks**

```
<head>
    {% block title %} {% endblock %}
</head>
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "default":
    {
        "title": "TITLE"
    },
    "test":
    {
        "title": "TEST TITLE"
    }
}
```

When compiled through gulp, two separate emails are created with their own title using the same template.